# I'm having trouble with my program running too long. I'm not sure if it's running infinitely or if it's just really slow

Tags: python

I'm writing a code to analyze a (8477960, 1) column vector. I am not sure if the while loops in my code are running infinitely, or if the way I've written things is just really slow.

This is a section of my code up to the first while loop, which I cannot get to run to completion.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\willo\Desktop\TF_60nm_2_2.txt')


def recursive_low_pass(rawsignal, startcoeff, endcoeff, filtercoeff):
    #  The current signal length

    ni = len(rawsignal)  # signal size
    rougheventlocations = np.zeros(shape=(100000, 3))

    # The algorithm parameters
    # filter coefficient
    a = filtercoeff
    raw = np.array(rawsignal).astype(np.float)

    # thresholds
    s = startcoeff
    e = endcoeff  # for event start and end thresholds

    # The recursive algorithm
    # loop init

    ml = np.zeros(ni)
    vl = np.zeros(ni)
    s = np.zeros(ni)

    ml[0] = np.mean(raw) # local mean init
    vl[0] = np.var(raw) # local variance init
    i = 0  # sample counter
    numberofevents = 0  # number of detected events

    # main loop
    while i < (ni - 1):
        i = i + 1
        # local mean low pass filtering
        ml[i] = a * ml[i - 1] + (1 - a) * raw[i]
        # local variance low pass filtering
        vl[i] = a * vl[i - 1] + (1 - a) * np.power([raw[i] - ml[i]],2)
        # local threshold to detect event start
        sl = ml[i] - s * np.sqrt(vl[i])
```

I'm not getting any error messages, but I've let the program run for more than 10 minutes without any results, so I assume I'm doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Have you tried adding some output in the while loop to see if there is progress, and if so, how fast?

Comment: How about trying `data.iloc[:100]` first to test your solution with only 100 entries in your dataframe?

Comment: Can you use a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to vectorize this process rather than accessing/processing indexes (otherwise why use numpy).

The other thing is that you seem to be doing unnecessary work (unless we're not seeing the whole function).

the line:

```
sl = ml[i] - s * np.sqrt(vl[i])
```

assigns the variable `sl` which you're not using inside the loop (or anywhere else).  This assignment performs a whole vector multiplication by s which is all zeroes.  If you do need the sl variable, you should calculate it outside of the loop using the last encountered values of ml[i] and vl[i] which you can store in temporary variables instead of computing on every loop.

If `ni` is in the millions, this unnecessary vector multiplication (of millions of zeros) is going to be very costly.

You probably didn't mean to override the value of `s = startcoeff` with `s = np.zeros(ni)` in the first place.

In order to vectorize these calculations you will need to use np.acumulate with some customized functions.

The non-numpy equivalent would be as follows (using itertools instead):

```
from itertools import accumulate

ml     = [np.mean(raw)]+[0]*(ni-1)
mlSums = accumulate(zip(ml,raw),lambda r,d:(a*r[0] + (1-a)*d[1],0))
ml     = [v for v,_ in mlSums]

vl     = [np.var(raw)]+[0]*(ni-1)
vlSums = accumulate(zip(vl,raw,ml),lambda r,d:(a*r[0] + (1-a)*(d[1]-d[2])**2,0,0))
vl     = [v for v,_,_ in vlSums]
```

In each case, the ml / vl vectors are initialized with the base value at index zero and the rest filled with zeroes.

The `accumulate(zip(...` function calls go through the array and call the lambda function with the current sum in `r` and the paired elements in `d`.  For the `ml` calculation, this corresponds to `r = (ml[i-1],_)` and `d = (0,raw[i])`.

Because accumulate ouputs the same date type as it is given as input (which are zipped tuples), the actual result is only the first value of the tuples in the mlSums/vlSums lists.

This took 9.7 seconds to process for 8,477,960 items in the lists.